# How to answer to command response? (shell_exec, exec)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I should enter confirmation code after my function execute. My command wait an answer but I can't reply.

```php
$cmd = 'cd/ && cd .... && ....';
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

I tried:

```php
shell_exec($confirmation_code);
```

I must enter confirmation code after get permission for some access.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand. Is executed command awaiting for key press?

Comment: Yes, it is waiting. Actually it likes y/n or new/set/quit questions. I can't answer the output but I should answer with new function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$cmd = 'echo "Yes"| cd/ && cd .... && ....';
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

Replace "Yes" by what you want

Comment: I tried. I expect a new question but output is blank page.

Answer (score 0):

Symphony Process command can do this for you:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#streaming-to-the-standard-input-of-a-process

Comment: I looked over but I didn't find what I'm looking for. Because Codeigniter has not Process and the like to my knowledge. Thanks anyway for help!

Comment: Do you use composer? If yes, then you can use that package

Comment: I will try. Thanks!